# Networking in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I'm a newbie when it comes to Kubernetes and the thing I am struggling to understand is the network address that I pass into the command `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=$ip` if I have two networks a public and private one. If I add the private one I can't connect to the proxy, although I feel if I add the public one kubernetes itself is exposed and a problematic solution for security. Not only that I also can't seem to expose services to the public address.

I did try to SSH tunnel to the proxy, it works but Kubernetes dashboard seems to give me a context error.

I essentially want the node to node communication on the private network.

Thanks for any advice in advance.
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--apiserver-advertise-address` is the IP address on which to advertise the apiserver to members of the cluster. This address must be reachable by the rest of the cluster. By default, it is the private IP of your master node where you're running `kubeadm init`. Also, It can be a L4 load balancer IP address, if your apiserver is behind the load balancer(generally happens in mutli master setup)

The another thing you talk about is `node to node` communication inside kubernetes cluster, and that happens through the CNI network. There are multiple CNI networks available on which you can choose, I recommend `weave` or `calico` both are quite stable.

For better understanding you can read:

https://chrislovecnm.com/kubernetes/cni/choosing-a-cni-provider/

To kick start with cluster creation, there is nothing better than kubernetes official doc:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I realise this although if I use the private IP I can't get external services and need to proxy. So how do I also define the public one?

Comment: You should able to ping your nodes with the internal IP address to make your cluster work seamlessly. Could you please check if you're able to ping your worker nodes with internal IP

Comment: They all can talk to each other via the private network

Comment: Are you using any CNI like `calico`, `weave` or `flannel`?

Comment: I am using calico

Comment: Could you please share the o/p of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`

Comment: I also can't paste it in as it's too large

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186187/room-for-prafull-ladha-and-jamie-bonnett Please join